# Sprite not spawning in correct position pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Ok so basically I'm making a rhythm game and I want beats to spawn at the right side of the screen when a certain time threshold is met.

It works the first time but when the second beat is called it spawns in the place the previous beat was killed. So if I call the first beat it spawns, moves along the screen and then is self killed when it reaches the miss area. But then when the second one is spawned, given the same coordinates it spawns in the place the first died, the miss area.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
import pygame
import random
import os
# outlines asset folders
img_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Graphics')
sound_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Audio')
# - Global Values for when game starts
WIDTH = 1080
HEIGHT = 720
FPS = 30
song_choice = "Georgia"
combo = 0
points = 0
lyric = "A"
time_elapsed = 0
cursor_position = 1

# define colors - Get rid of later
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)

# initialize pygame and create window
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Eurovision: The Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Short_Beat(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, top, left):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,50))
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = top
        self.rect.y = left
    def update(self):
        # - If song selected then speed is
       if song_choice == "Georgia": # - Echoes - Iru - 1
           self.rect.x += -6
       elif song_choice == "Ukraine": # - Shum Go_A - 4
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Serbia": # - Corpre sano Konstrakta - 1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Finland": # - Cha Cha Cha Kaarija -1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Sweden": # - Tattoo Loreen -1 
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice =="France": # - Evidament La Zarra -1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice =="Estonia": # - Bridges Estonia - 1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Malta": # - Dance (our own Party) The Busker -3
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Italy": # - Zitti e Buoni Maneskin - 4
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Austria": # - Who the hell is edgar Teya and Salena -2
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Norway": # - Queen of the Kings Alessandra - 1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Armenia": # - Future Lover Brunette - 1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Azerbaijan": # - Mata Hari Efendi -1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "United Kingdom": # Mae Muller I wrote a song - 1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Slovenia": #Carpe Diem Joker out - 5
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Moldova": #Soarele Si Luna - 2
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Croatia": # - Mama SC Let 3 - 5
           self.rect.x += 0 
       elif song_choice == "Neatherlands": # - Arcade Duncan Laurence 
           self.rect.x += 0
class Long_Beat(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, top, left):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((300,50))
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = top
        self.rect.y = left
    def update(self):
        # - If song selected then speed is
       if song_choice == "Georgia": # - Echoes - Iru - 1
           self.rect.x += -6
       elif song_choice == "Ukraine": # - Shum Go_A - 1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Serbia": # - Corpre sano Konstrakta - 1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Finland": # - Cha Cha Cha Kaarija -1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Sweden": # - Tattoo Loreen -1 
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice =="France": # - Evidament La Zarra -1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice =="Estonia": # - Bridges Estonia - 1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Malta": # - Dance (our own Party) The Busker -3
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Italy": # - Zitti e Buoni Maneskin - 4
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Austria": # - Who the hell is edgar Teya and Salena -2
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Norway": # - Queen of the Kings Alessandra - 1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Armenia": # - Future Lover Brunette - 1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Azerbaijan": # - Mata Hari Efendi -1
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Australia": # Promise Voyager - 5
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Slovenia": #Carpe Diem Joker out - 5
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Romania": #Soarele Si Luna - 2
           self.rect.x += 0
       elif song_choice == "Croatia": # - Mama SC Let 3 - 5
           self.rect.x += 0 
       elif song_choice == "Neatherlands": # - Arcade Duncan Laurence - 1 38 sprites in total 120 frames each 4 seconds of animation
           self.rect.x += 0
# - Thresholds to determine accuracy
class Failure(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10,50))
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (int(WIDTH / 2), int(HEIGHT / 2))
        self.rect.x = 50
        self.rect.y = 360
class Perfect(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10,50))
        self.image.fill(YELLOW)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (int(WIDTH / 2), int(HEIGHT / 2))
        self.rect.x = 211
        self.rect.y = 360
class Near_Perfect(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((75,50))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (int(WIDTH / 2), int(HEIGHT / 2))
        self.rect.x = 221
        self.rect.y = 360
class Near_Miss(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((75,50))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 136
        self.rect.y = 360
# - Get a nice, pixely font later
font_name = pygame.font.match_font('arial')
def draw_text (surf, text, size, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.Font(font_name, size)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.midtop = (x,y)
    surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
class Artist_Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,song_choice, top):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 
        self.song_choice = song_choice
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'Georgia0.png')).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = top
        self.rect.y = 450
        self.value = 0
    def update(self):
        # - This list outlines the images used in the animations - Which song's artist then which frame of their animation
        image_sprite_list = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir,song_choice + "0.png")),
                        pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir,song_choice + "1.png"))]
        # - Every frame the value increases
        if self.value >= len(image_sprite_list):
            self.value = 0
        self.image = image_sprite_list[self.value]
        # - Every second increases the value which then dictates the frame of animation
        self.value += 1
        if combo == 0:
            print('annoyed face')
class Cursor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'Cursor.png')).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 1000
        self.rect.y = 360
    def update(self):
        if cursor_position == 1:
            self.rect.x = 100
            self.rect.y = 200
        if cursor_position == 2:
            self.rect.x = 100
            self.rect.y = 200  
background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'Title_Screen.png')).convert()
background_rect = background.get_rect()
title_screen_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'Title_Screen.png')).convert()
song_select_screen_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, 'Song_Select_Screen.png')).convert()
def Title_Screen():
    screen.blit(title_screen_img, background_rect)
    draw_text(screen, "Press a key to begin", 18, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT * 3 / 4)
    pygame.display.flip()
    waiting = True
    while waiting:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                waiting = False
def Song_Select_Screen():
    screen.blit(song_select_screen_img, background_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    Cursor()
    waiting = True
    cursor_position = 1
    while waiting:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                cursor_position = cursor_position + 1
                
# - Define Sprites

# - Define Sounds
Georgia = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(sound_dir,'Georgia.mp3'))
# - Define sprite groups
beat = pygame.sprite.Group()
short_beat_defined = Short_Beat(1080,360)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
near_perfect_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
perfect_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
miss_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
near_miss_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

miss = Failure()
miss_group.add(miss)
perfect_defined = Perfect()
perfect_group.add(perfect_defined)
near_perfect_defined = Near_Perfect()
near_perfect_group.add(near_perfect_defined)
near_miss_defined = Near_Miss()
near_miss_group.add(near_miss_defined)
artist_sprite_defined = Artist_Sprite(song_choice, 500)
# - Define All_Sprite Group
all_sprites.add(miss_group)
all_sprites.add(perfect_group)
all_sprites.add(near_perfect_group)
all_sprites.add(near_miss_group)
         
# - Below is the code which selects the song level after being decided by the player
# Game loop
running = True
game_started = False
# - The time when the game begins running
time_elapsed = 0
while running:
    # keep loop running at the right speed
    clock.tick(FPS)  
    # - Displays the title screen
    if not game_started:
        # - Title Screen and other selection screens are under construction 
        #Title_Screen()
        #Song_Select_Screen()
        game_started = True
    # Process input (events)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    # Update
    all_sprites.update()
    # - Check for Collisons with objects
    miss_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(short_beat_defined,miss_group, False)
    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    perfect_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(short_beat_defined,perfect_group, False, pygame.sprite.collide_rect_ratio(0.5))
    near_perfect_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(short_beat_defined,near_perfect_group, False,pygame.sprite.collide_rect_ratio(0.5))
    near_miss_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(short_beat_defined, near_miss_group, False, pygame.sprite.collide_rect_ratio(0.5))
    if keystate[pygame.K_y]:
        if perfect_hit:
            print("Perfect!")
            short_beat_defined.kill()
            combo = combo + 1
            points = points + 15
        elif near_perfect_hit:
            print('Okay')
            draw_text(screen, "Okay!", 160, 360, 0)
            short_beat_defined.kill()
            combo = combo + 1
            points = points + 5
        elif near_miss_hit:
            print('Okay')
            short_beat_defined.kill()
            draw_text(screen, "Okay", 160, 360, 0)
            combo = combo + 1
            points = points + 5
        else:
            print('Miss!')
            draw_text(screen, ("Miss!"), 500, 360, 0)
            short_beat_defined.kill()
            combo = 0
    if miss_hit:
        print('Miss')
        draw_text(screen, "Miss!", 500, 360, 0)
        short_beat_defined.kill()
        combo = 0        
    # Draw / render
    time_elapsed = time_elapsed + 1 # - 1800 per minute
    if time_elapsed == 1:
        # Georgia.play()
        Artist_Sprite(song_choice, 900)
        all_sprites.add(artist_sprite_defined)
        Short_Beat(1080,360)
        beat.add(short_beat_defined)
        all_sprites.add(beat)
    if time_elapsed == 266:
        Short_Beat(1080,360)
        beat.add(short_beat_defined)
        all_sprites.add(beat)
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    draw_text(screen, str(f"{combo}"), 39, 200, 0)
    draw_text(screen, str(f"{time_elapsed}"), 39, 475, 0)
    draw_text(screen, str(f"{points}"), 39, 375, 0)
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief, it looks like you're creating new sprites, but not adding them to the sprite group, instead you're adding the previously generated sprites.

Change:

```
Artist_Sprite(song_choice, 900)
all_sprites.add(artist_sprite_defined)
Short_Beat(1080,360)
beat.add(short_beat_defined)
```

To:

```
new_arty = Artist_Sprite(song_choice, 900)
all_sprites.add(new_arty)
new_shorty = Short_Beat(1080,360)
beat.add(new_shorty)
all_sprites.add(new_shorty)
```

You could combine the first two lines to `all_sprites.add(Artist_Sprite(song_choice, 900))`.

Additionally, pygame supports [Named Colors](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color_list.html), so instead of defining your own color tuples, you can supply strings, e.g. `screen.fill("black")`.